# What is remoteObjectPort in enCache

Tags: java, replication, ehcache

I have been following the ehCache documentation regarding replication on https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/replication/rmi-replicated-caching.html

EhCache is already implemented in our project, but going through the code base, I am seeing at multiple places regarding `remoteObjectPort` being added in properties while configuring the listener.

Here is our code to add peer information to the `peerProviderConfig`

```
   FactoryConfiguration peerProviderConfig = new FactoryConfiguration();
   peerProviderConfig.setClass(RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory.class
                    .getName());

   for (CacheHost remoteHost : remoteHosts) {
        // create a RMI URL
        rmiUrls += separator
        createRmiUrl(remoteHost, cacheName);
        separator = "|";
    }

     // and set it in configuration
     peerProviderConfig.setProperties("peerDiscovery=manual, rmiUrls=" + rmiUrls);
```

I understand this piece of code. This will build and append the url for all the peers.
The `createRmiUrl()` method returns url as follows: `//<hostname>:<hostport>/cacheName`

For all the hosts, the `hostport` is same that is `40001`. This means that on all the different hosts, ehCache will be running on port `40001`. According to my understanding following things happen:

1. Whenever a peer comes alive, it will start the ehCache on port 40001
2. It will also configure all the peers in the cluster as we are using `manual discovery`
3. It will listen for some events and then update/ replicate its own data in the cache.

Is my understanding right?

Our `PeerListenerProperties` are as follows:

```
   String peerListenerProps = "port=" + rmiPort;
   peerListenerProps += ", remoteObjectPort=40002";
   peerListenerProps += ", socketTimeoutMillis=" + socketTimeoutMillis;

   FactoryConfiguration peerListenerConfig = new FactoryConfiguration();
   peerListenerConfig.setClass(RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory.class.getName());
   peerListenerConfig.setProperties(peerListenerProps);
```

So in the listener properties, we are adding `port = rmiPort` (which is `40001` and the same will be used by all the peers/hosts). What I don't understand is what is the usage of `remoteObjectPort` in the listener properties?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the port for the TCP connection of your remote stub object.

If you do not specify a port, it will get a random TCP port for each stub object when trying to comunicate data between servers.